# Change Scrollbar Shape (CSS3)

Tags: css, scrollbar

I am making a custom scrollbar for a site. Currently I have it in an oval shape using `border-radius` but would like the ends to be sharp, like a triangle. I need just the handle of the scroll bar changed, and this is what I currently have for the oval shape:

`::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #d62222; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}`

Comment: Do you need something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/YWnzc/237/

Comment: not quite... I was talking about the side scroll bar, so something like this (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp) just pointed instead of rounded

Comment: i have now figured out that it isnt possible to do what i wanted

Comment: Please add the answer below if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you might be looking for to use percentage instead of pixel in the `border-radius`, for example:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #d62222; 
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

This way the scrollbar has a more sharp shape instead of an oval. You can play with different percentages to get what you need.